# Get the result of an analysis as a JSON in SolR

Tags: json, solr, analysis

I made a filter in SolR as following :

```
<fieldtype name="tokenization_stopwords" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>  
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

When I'm using this filter in the "Analysis" section, it works. However, I'd like to be able
to get the result of this analysis as a JSON.
Does anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get that you need to configure the `FieldAnalysisRequestHandler` in your solrconfig.xml and ask him questions.

```xml
<requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler"/>
```

The request would look like this

> http:// localhost:8989/solr/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.fieldvalue=test+dog+cat&analysis.fieldtype=tokenization_stopwords

For more information have a look [in the javadoc of the FieldAnalysisRequestHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.html)