# Can I query the result of Solr stemming and stop-words?

Tags: rest, solr

We use Solr including language-dependent stemming and stop-words, all works fine.

However, we use search in other parts of the application as well where the documents are not in a Solr index. I’d like to filter out stop-words there as well. Is there any Solr query that returns its arguments with stop-words removed? Or in general, with filters applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written here in the SO question [Get the result of an analysis as a JSON in SolR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453220/get-the-result-of-an-analysis-as-a-json-in-solr)

You can configure the `FieldAnalysisRequestHandler` in your solrconfig.xml and ask him questions.

```xml
<requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler"/>
```

The request would look like this

> http:// localhost:8989/solr/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.fieldvalue=test+dog+cat&analysis.fieldtype=tokenization_stopwords

For more information have a look [in the javadoc of the FieldAnalysisRequestHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.html)